# DynamicDataDisplay : How to change Gregorian calendar to some other calendar

Tags: gregorian-calendar, persian, dynamic-data-display

I am currently working on showing a Chart with **DynamicDataDisplay** .
My problem is that *HorizontalDateTime* only support *Gregorian Calendar* , but I want to change that to some other calendar. 
for example *Persian calendar* .
`using System.Globalization;
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();`
Can anyone help me.

Thanks .

```
   <d3:ChartPlotter Name="ChartPlotter" Margin="10,10,20,10">
        <d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
            <d3:HorizontalDateTimeAxis Name ="HorizontalDateTime"/>
        </d3:ChartPlotter.HorizontalAxis>
    </d3:ChartPlotter>
```

Comment: `PersianCalendar` is the weakness of many tools. This is one of the last things to be supported as 'full Persian support' in almost any software tools unfortunately.

Comment: Yes ! lack of documentation in this library is really a downside . Do you know any other library that support Persian calender or with possibility of overriding them ?